# Display a page without additional header/footer/etc in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

If you look at [this website](http://physio.weboptic.co.uk/) and look at the bottom, you'll see a link saying "This link should open the ask the expert box.". When you click that you'll see it opens a link in a new lightbox window. The problem I have is that it's displaying the page with all of the content (i.e. the header and footer) and I just want it to display the ask the expert box.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add more details how you are using the fancybox to open that page in window?

Comment: Fancybox just opens up an iframe which links to [this](http://physio.weboptic.co.uk/ask-the-expert-home-ask-box) page.

`<a class="fancybox-iframe" href="/ask-the-expert-home-ask-box">This link should open the ask the expert box.</a>`

Comment: Is this page a wordpress page or post?

Comment: Hello man it is very simple. Just add a file to your theme. you can read more at http://techbymak.com/create-blank-wordpress-page-with-no-sidebar-no-footer-no-header.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `template` which will not include header and footer.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Some Name
*/
?>
```

and assign this template to `ask-the-expert-home-ask-box` page from admin site of wordpress.

Checkout [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) for more info

Alternately, You can also use the `custom field` feature of wordpress.

You can create a custom field with `ask-the-expert-home-ask-box` this page.

Lets says field name is `include_header` and value is set to `false` 
and then you can check this field in the `single.php` file if it is set to false do't include header and footer.

Comment: I actually tried this but because I'm using Thematic theme framework, things got problematic... http://pastebin.com/uuFRVkdX

Comment: @Chrish: Cooment out `//get_header();` and `//get_footer();`

Comment: Be sure to include `wp_head();` within the `head` section of your template, and `wp_footer();` at the bottom of your template as these are vital.